# $\exp(x)-\exp(y)$ coordinate system embedded in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification, coordinate-systems, transformation

Define a coordinate system in $\Bbb R^2$ with an exponential scale on the axes: $\exp(x)-\exp(y).$ Then embed this coordinate system in the first quadrant of $\Bbb R^2$ such that we view the axes now as cartesian $x-y$ coordinates.

You can think of all this as a map $f$ which transforms points in $\Bbb R^2.$

$f:\Bbb R^2\to(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ with $f(x,y)=(e^x,e^y).$

As an example consider a curve $xy=1$ embedded in $\Bbb R^2.$ Change the scale of the axes both to exponential, to obtain $\log(x)\log(y)=1.$ And then let the axes be cartesian $x-y$ coordinates.

Another way to think about it is to transform the points in $\Bbb R^2$ via $f.$ The pre-image space will have the algebraic equation $xy=1$ while the image space will have transformed this algebraic equation to $\log(x)\log(y)=1.$ Note: via the subsitution $u=\log(x)$ and $v=\log(y)$ you can see that $uv=1$ is a hyperbola. This means to transfer from an $\exp(x)-\exp(y)$ coordinate system to a cartesian $x-y$ system you just have to take the logarithm of each ordered pair of points in the space.

Here is a picture depicting the transformation $f.$ I labeled some points $a,b,c,d$ before the transformation and show where they end up after the transformation.

[image]

> Now there is an exponential-exponential coordinate system of $\Bbb R^2$ embedded within the cartesian first quadrant of $\Bbb R^2$ itself? Can this be right?

Comment: You mean $f(x,y)=[exp(exp(x)),exp(exp(y))]$? So this maps to $(1,\infty)^2$...IMO, you can embed this into the first quadrant, it's just not onto...

Comment: @Engineertryingmath I mean I meant $f(x,y)=(\exp(x),\exp(y))$

Comment: I just try to understand what your question is. Might it be "does this mean that there is a bijection  between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(0,\infty)^2$? Can this be, because the former contains the latter"? The answer to this question would be: correct! It's similar to the bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$.